# Watson's lemma with cubic term

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, asymptotics, complex-integration

I know how to use Watson's Lemma to find asymptotic expansions for integrals of the form:
$$ F_1(\lambda) = \int_0^\infty \phi(t) e^{-\lambda t} dt$$
under suitable conditions on the integrability of $\phi(t)$.
An extension of this method can be applied integrals where the exponential term is changed to
$F_2(\lambda) := \int_{-a}^a \phi(t) e^{-\lambda t^2} dt$ or even $F_4(\lambda) =
\int_{-a}^a \phi(t) e^{-\lambda t^4} dt $.
To find the asymptotics of $F_2$ and $F_4$  one essentially splits the integral in odd and even parts, and reduce it to one of type $F_1$, and apply Watson's directly.

However, what can we say about
$$ F_3(\lambda) = \int_{\gamma} \phi(t) e^{-\lambda t^3} dt,$$
where $\gamma$ is some contours in the complex plane passing through zero?

For these types of integrals one usually tries to use Laplace method, but since the Inverse Function Theorem fails when applied to the change of variables $t^3 = s^2$, it cannot reduced to an integral of shape $F_2$.

Cheers,
VECH

Comment: $F_3$ has a double saddle point at $t=0$ (i.e, both $f'$ and $f''$ vanishes at the origin, $f(t)=t^3$). You may deform the contour of integration to one of the $3$ doubly-infinite contours of steepest descent through the origin and apply the method of steepest descents.

Comment: What is $\gamma$ and $\phi$

Comment: @Gary, how can one apply steepest descent to $f(t) = t^3$ or more generally, to an exponent function where the $f(t)$ vanishes to higher order? My understanding of steepest descent is that once boils down the problem to an integral of type $F_2$ where we can apply Watson's lemma directly. But I cannot do this for the reasons mentioned above.

Comment: The method is well-developed for higher-order saddles as well. Take a look at, for example, R. Wong's "Asymptotic Approximations of Integrals", Chapter II, Section 4.

Comment: As indicated above, the answer will depend on $\phi$ and $\gamma$. If $\phi(t) = e^{-t^4}$ and $\gamma = \mathbb R$, the integral can be approximated by taking $t = \lambda u$ and restricting the integration range to an arbitrarily small interval around $u = -3/4$.